# NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass): / Action Mailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I try to use ActionMailer to automatically send an email notification when someone receives a message in my website. I use Devise for user authentification.

I keep receiving this message in my terminal when I test the mailer :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):
app/mailers/app_mailer.rb:6:in `new_message'
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Here is mys files :
app/mailers/app_mailer.rb

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default from: "no-reply@adventurer.com"

  def new_message(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Vous avez un nouveau message')
end

end
```

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

```
def create
        @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
        @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

        if @message.save

          AppMailer.new_message(@user).deliver_now
          respond_to do |format|
            format.js            
          end
        end        
    end
```

Can anyone help me ? I don't understand why it does not recognize the .email method on user, which does exist.
Thank you !

Edit :
I have that in conversation.rb

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'

  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :recipient_id

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
       where("conversations.sender_id = ? OR conversations.recipient_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
   end

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
       where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)

   end

end
```

In messages_controller.rb

```
def create
        @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
        @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

        if @message.save

      AppMailer.new_message(@user).deliver_now
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js            
      end
    end        
end
```

And in my app_mailer.rb

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@adventurer.com"

  def new_message(user)
    @user = User.find(@conversations.recipient_id)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Vous avez un nouveau message')
  end
end
```

And I get this in my terminal when I try to send a message : NoMethodError (undefined method `recipient_id' for nil:NilClass)

Thanks again for the help ;)

Edit
messages_controller.rb

```
def create
        @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
        @messages = @conversation.messages.order("created_at DESC")

        if @message.save
          @user = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id)    
          AppMailer.new_message(@user).deliver_now
          respond_to do |format|
            format.js            
          end
        end        
    end
```

app_mailer.rb

```
class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@adventurer.com"

  def new_message(user)
    @user = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id)    
     mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Vous avez un nouveau message')

  end
end
```

Comment: "user which does exist" - nowhere in your code (that we see) you initialize it. It does not exist.

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks, Where should I initialize it ? User.email exists, all the authentification / user creation works well, I can log in without problem

Comment: You should initialize before using it. It's your app and your app logic. We can't possibly know what `@user` is supposed to mean there.

Comment: In which file / with which code ? I'm not sure to understand what I'm missing since I already created User.email... Thanks :)

Comment: "I'm not sure to understand what I'm missing" - you're missing `@user = whatever` somewhere close to initializing `@message`.

Comment: In all the tutorials I read, we just have to call @user.email in the method. What should I include in the def new_message(user) ?

Comment: "What should I include in the def new_message(user)" - nothing. You should initialize it in the action (`def create`). As to how _exactly_ you should initialize it, again, I can't possibly tell, because I don't know your app logic and what `@user` means.

Comment: I'm quite sure all those tutorials also include the bit where they initialize the user.

Comment: All right, I have the following code in def create. It's supposed to send an email when a message is posted.  AppMailer.new_message(@user).deliver_now

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï Yes, that's the whole point. You can't just reference `@user` and expect rails to magically know what `@user` is supposed to mean. You need to, **for example(!!!)** do: `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`. How does the `MessagesController` know which user to send the message to?

Comment: Hi Tom and Sergio, Ok i get it, sorry I'm a total beginner. I added @user = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id) to the def new_message but it still send me an error message.. I'm  a bit confused (recipient_id exists in my conversation in my conversation model)

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï: but where do you initialize conversation? And what are its fields/values? And what's the error? Help us help you, don't make us pull these bits of crucial information from you with vice grips.

Comment: Just added the information about my conversations.rb and messages_controller.rb ;)

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï If you want to send the message to the recipient you can just do `AppMailer.new_message(@conversation.recipent).deliver_now` in your controller. Have a look at the [Rails Guides - Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more details about the mailer.

Comment: Your solution of `@user = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id)` also works, but only if you do it in the Controller (before using `@user`) where `@conversation` is actually initialized. In the `AppMailer` `@conversation` is uninitialized and thus will raise an *"NoMethodError: undefined method \`recipent_id' for nil:NilClass"* exception.

Comment: Having a look at the [Ruby Assignment documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html) might also help you out quite a bit here.

Comment: Great, thank you very much Johan, I'll try it your way !

Answer (score 0):

Your `@user` object didnt initialized. Thats why you are getting this error. You can initialize it from your `@conversation` object i guess. Assuming `@conversation` objects holds `sender_id` and `receiver_id` or something like this. Try to initialize `@user` by `@user = User.find(@conversation.receiver_id)` or `@user = User.find(@conversation.sender_id)` depending which one is sender and the other receiver. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks a lot, really helpful ! So you mean that my app_mailer.rb should look like this ? => class AppMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@adventurer.com"

  def new_message(user)
    User.find(@conversations.recipient_id)
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Vous avez un nouveau message')
  end
end

Comment: I think its better to initialize `@user` in `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb` in `create` method and then pass `@user` to ``AppMailer.new_message`` method. But since i don't know your app your solution may work too.

Comment: @MatthieuLallaï No. If the `new_message` method takes a `user`, then you should pass that in. Or if it takes a `conversation`, then you should pass that in instead. Look at where the variables are being defined, where they're getting sent, and where they're getting used.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment on your last explanation because of my low reputation. `@user = User.find(@conversations.recipient_id)` take this line to `create` method. You are getting same error by uninitialized `@conversations` object this time.

Comment: You mean in the messages_controller ?

Comment: Yeah. you can put that line after `if @message.save` line.

Comment: Thanks, but still does not work, saying "undefined method `recipient_id'". I guess I miss something in initializing @conversations but I don't know what I should add..

Comment: Not `@conversations` drop the 's'.

Comment: still does not work.. I should put it in the two files ?

Comment: can you upload your last changes  and all lines of your message_controller.rb

Comment: delete `@user = User.find(@conversation.recipient_id)` line from `AppMailer`. You already have this line in `messages_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried, but it now tells me again "NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):"

Comment: if you pushed this app to github i can help, otherwise you must debug this process by your own. there is gem called 'binding_of_caller'  easy to use. simply put `binding.pry` line anywhere in your code to start debugging from.

Comment: Great thanks a lot Mehmet ! I'll try to debug with this gem :)